# Fabric problems with reloading supervisor on remote host

Tags: python, django, fabric, supervisord, webfaction

My project is hosted on Webfaction and supervisor is used to be aware of processes.
I use shell utils to get the PID of supervisor and it works just fine when I do it manually, but I got random PIDs when executing the same command remotely with Fabric

#### Code to get PID of supervisor

```
spid = run('ps auxw | grep supervisord | grep %s | tr -s \' \' | cut -d\  -f 2' % USER)

if spid:                   # if supervisor is running and PID is found
    run('kill %s' % spid)  # kill supervidor daemon
```

I'm confused why I get random PIDs when calling command remotely, what is wrong with the way I do it?

Thanks,

Sultan

Comment: What does a "random" pid look like? Could it be the PID of a process that was killed?

Comment: The above command returns None if supervisor is not running, so I my case when executing command remotely with Fabric I've wrong PIDs though if I check manually the same command I got correct PID

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could solve this simpler by using `pkill` or `pgrep` to find the pid. But also if that's all you're doing I'd say use the `-j|--pidfile=` option so you don't have to look it up through the process output.

Comment: Thank you @Morgan. By the way I used command like `ps -u imanhodjaev -o rss,etime,pid,command` to figure out PIDs